# Getting row with MAX value together with SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a PostgreSQL table `example` with three columns: `a INT, b INT, c TEXT`.

For each value of `a` I want the `c` with the highest value of `b`, together with the sum of all `b`. Something like (if there was an ARGMAX function):

```
SELECT a, ARGMAX(c for MAX(b)), SUM(b) FROM example GROUP BY a
```

I've found a lot of solutions with varying techniques to get the ARGMAX bit, but none of them seem to use GROUP BY, so I was wondering what we most efficient way would be to capture the SUM (or other aggregate functions) as well.

Comment: What? Please give us sample of data ad expected output!

Comment: For each value of a I want the c with the highest value of b, together with the sum of all b.   I have to go back to school to understand that..!!!

Comment: select a, max(c) over (partition by a), sum(b) over (partition by a, c) from table group by a

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Why don't you post it?

Comment: Right now i'm just lazy xP and I like to create a fiddle in such answers it would take time some time... feel free though :) if it is right use it as answer :) @ClodoaldoNeto

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Thanks :) Save for a `DISTINCT` on `a` it seems to work, albeit more slowly than @Giorgos Betsos's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using window functions:

```
SELECT a, b, c, s
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b DESC) AS rn,
         SUM(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS s
  FROM example) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

- `ROW_NUMBER` enumerates records within each `a` partition: the record having the highest `b` value is assigned a value of 1, next record a value of 2, etc.
- `SUM(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a)` returns the sum of all `b` within each `a` partition.